# Cloned div values not send through POST

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript function that clones a div which contains a inputfield, now the problem is that the cloned inputfield values isnt send through post. Only the first value of the array gets a value.

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Post button:

```
if(isset($_POST['VolgendeStap'])) {
  $phonenumberAmount = count($_POST['phoneNumbers']);

    echo $phonenumberAmount;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $_POST['phoneNumbers'][0];
    echo $_POST['phoneNumbers'][1];
}
```

Divs with inputfield

```
echo "<div class='allPhoneNumbers'>";
    for($j = 0; $j < $phonenumberAmount; $j++) {


        echo "<div id='phoneNumber{$j}'>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='phoneNumbers[]'>";
            echo "<input type='button' class='removeButton' value='x'>";
        echo "</div>";

        echo '<script>';
        echo 'current++;';
        echo '</script>';

    }

    echo "</div>";
    echo "<input type='button' id='cloneButton' onclick='cloneDiv(phoneNumber0);' value='Nog een nummer'>";
```

Javascript:

```
var max = 5;
var current = 0;

// Duplicates the DIV
function cloneDiv(divID) {

    if(current < max) {

        var newDiv = $(divID).clone();
        newDiv.attr("id", "phoneNumber"+current);

        current++;

        newDiv.children()[0].value = '';
        newDiv.find(".removeButton").show();
        newDiv.children()[1].onclick = function() {
            $(this.parentNode).remove();
            current--;
            if(current < max) {
                $("#cloneButton").show();
            }
        };

        newDiv.appendTo(".allPhoneNumbers");

        if(current == max) {
            $("#cloneButton").hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST['phoneNumbers'])` to examine what exactly is send back to your server. If this is not, what you expect, use the developer tools of the browser of your choice to examine the dynamically created html code.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are declaring the "var current = 0" on every page load, and when you post the form it executes that part of code (couse it causes the page to reload) and that's why you always see only the first one. You should have a function that sets the "current" initial and future values by actually counting the number of divs. Let me know if it works out, cheers!